# War File Deployment Fail

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {
    \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\\\".component.\\\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener\\\".WeldInstantiator\" => \"Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyProcessor (Module \\\"deployment.demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\\\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerWriteProcessor (Module \\\"deployment.demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\\\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Processor\",
    \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\\\".component.\\\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener\\\".WeldInstantiator\" => \"Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestBodyPublisher (Module \\\"deployment.demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\\\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/AbstractListenerReadPublisher (Module \\\"deployment.demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\\\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Publisher\",
    \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\\\".component.\\\"org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HttpHandlerAsyncListener\\\".WeldInstantiator\" => \"Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HttpHandlerAsyncListener
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module \\\"deployment.demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\\\" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber\"
}}"
```

I have cleaned the project and updated maven dependencies

Comment: Can you format your question a little bit? It is very hard to read. And what changes did you made in your dependencies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.